# WriteFile on a named pipe sometimes returns ERROR_NO_DATA

Tags: c++, winapi, named-pipes

I've got a C++ program that is creating a named pipe to write data to. Some customers have reported a situation where the client connects to the named pipe but the server end fails to write the data (with `ERROR_NO_DATA`).

This error code isn't really explained in any MSDN page that I could find; does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Or what the cause is?

### Open code:

```
ostringstream pipeName;
pipeName << "\\\\.\\pipe\\unique-named-pipe-" << GetCurrentProcessId();

pipeHandle = CreateNamedPipeA(
    pipeName.str().c_str(),              // pipe name
    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,                  // open mode
    PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE, // pipe mode
    PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,            // max instances
    512,                                 // output buffer size
    512,                                 // input buffer size
    0,                                   // use default timeouts
    NULL);                               // security attributes

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == pipeHandle)
{
    THROW("Failed to create named pipe", GetLastError());
}

cout << "Pipe ready" << endl;

// Wait for a client to connect to the pipe        
BOOL status = ConnectNamedPipe(pipeHandle, NULL);

if (!status)
{
    DWORD lastError = GetLastError();

    if (ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED != lastError)
    {
        THROW("Failed to wait for client to open pipe", lastError);
    }
    else
    {
        // Ignore, see MSDN docs for ConnectNamedPipe() for details.
    }
}
```

### Writing code:

```
// response is a std::string
int writeOffset = 0;
int length = response.length();

while ((int) response.length() > writeOffset)
{
    DWORD bytesWritten;

    BOOL status = WriteFile(
        pipeHandle,
        response.c_str() + writeOffset,
        length - writeOffset,
        &bytesWritten,
        NULL);

    if (!status)
    {
        // This sometimes fails with ERROR_NO_DATA, why??
        THROW("Failed to send via named pipe", GetLastError());
    }

    writeOffset += bytesWritten;
}
```

### Throw macro

```
#define THROW(message, errorCode) \
{ \
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: line: %d file: %s error:0x%x\n", \
            message, __LINE__, __FILE__, errorCode); \
    fflush(stderr); \
    throw message; \
} \
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that your moving outside the char array in response.c_str() + writeOffset

Comment: @rerun I don't think so, I've added in the writing loop so you can see what is happening.

Comment: Can't see what the THROW macro does.  Call GetLastError() *before* the statement.

Comment: @Hans I've added the code for the THROW macro too.

Comment: Hmya, you are assuming that retrieving stderr does not alter the thread's last error state.  Maybe it doesn't, it gets pretty muddled when you build with /MD.  Macros like that are evil, inline functions are not.

Comment: It's a stupidly named error code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at WinError.h, which is where this and other error codes are defined:

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_NO_DATA
//
// MessageText:
//
// The pipe is being closed.
//
#define ERROR_NO_DATA                    232L
```

Sounds like the client has already closed their end of the pipe - perhaps the client code thinks it has already got the full string, closes their end, while the code above continues to try to write?

Comment: The client end is definitely expecting more data and gets an unexpected EOF type error. As far as I can tell the client end is not closing the pipe first.

Comment: This [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365605(v=vs.85).aspx) mentions `ERROR_NO_DATA` as a possibility if the client closes the pipe while the server is attempting to read from it but it doesn't explain the writing case.

Comment: It's not explicitly called out on MSDN, but there's a few web pages out there that indicate that this error also applies to WriteFile - here's some sample code from MSDN that uses it: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190351  You might want to post the client-side code. How does the client know when to close the pipe or when it has the full string? Does this ever happen on the first Write in the loop, or only on second or later calls?

Comment: I have seen `ERROR_NO_DATA` on the very first `WriteFile` from the server, before the client called `CloseHandle`. However, in this scenario the client used `WriteFile` first, sent a variable-length string, and the server failed its matching `ReadFile` (`GetLastError=109, ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE`).